# how to create query from my table please check pic

Tags: sql

[image]

I would like to query with the result of

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help you frame a good question to make it easier for people to help you. In particular giving a minimal piece of code which demonstrates your problem rather than an image helps with testing

Comment: `dalam proses` and `selesai`. Are these the only valid values for column `ket`? By the way, it is recommended to also tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Are you using SQL Server? Are you using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can select the values without grouping:

```
select name, case when ket = 'dalam proses' then 1 else 0 end dalam_proses, 'selesai' then 1 else 0 end selesai
from yourtable;
```

Let's use it as a subquery:

```
select name, sum(dalam_proses) as dalam_proses, sum(selesai) as selesai
from (
    select name, case when ket = 'dalam proses' then 1 else 0 end dalam_proses, 'selesai' then 1 else 0 end selesai
    from yourtable
} t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using subquery, like this :

```
select 
    name, 
    distinct(name) , 
    count(select ket from my_table where ket = 'dalam proses' ) as 'dalam proses',
    count(select ket from my_table where ket = 'selesai' ) as 'selesai'
from my_table
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expressions to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
select name,
       sum(case when ket = 'dalam proses' then 1 else 0 end) as dalam_proses,
       sum(case when ket = 'selesai' then 1 else 0 end) as selesai
from tablename
group by name
```